# Delphi XE7 Mobile Transfer Image

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have an app that transmits the image to a remote server. It is working fine .
But if the user touches the screen it crashes the app and returns " not working " or "app is not responding ."
I wanted:

1) temporarily lock the screen.

2) I was using Application.ProcessMessages ; for the app not stop. Is corret ?

```
var
  lista:tlista;
  proxy: TServerMethods2Client;
  i:integer;
  trans: TDBXTransaction;
  Myvisita:TvisitaDs;
  MyEventos:TEve_ClIDS;
  Protoco:Tprotocolo;
  Ini: TIniFile;
  MyAnexos : TAnexosDs;
  oArquivoJSON: TJSONArray;

begin

try
   Datasnap.close;
   with Datasnap do
        begin
            Params.Values['HostName'] := Edit2.Text;
            Params.Values['Port'] := '211';
       end;


                Datasnap.Connected:=true;

                Ini :=TIniFile.Create(TPath.Combine(GetHomePath,'maitech.ini'));
                Ini.WriteString('Conexao','Path',Edit2.Text);
                Ini.Free;

    except
          on e:exception do
                begin
                       mensagem('Sem conexão com o servidor remoto',0);
                       exit;
                end;

    end;
  AniIndicator1.Enabled:=true;
  AniIndicator1.Visible:=true;

  { testa a conexao }
    try
      Datasnap.Open;
      proxy := nil;
      proxy := TServerMethods2Client.Create(Datasnap.DBXConnection);

    except
      on e: Exception do
      begin
           ShowMessage('Sem conexão com o servidor central' + #13 + 'Evento:' +          e.Message);
           exit;
      end;
    end;


          lista:=Tlista.Create;
          lista := lista.JSON_To_Lista(proxy.Data_to_Mobile(FormPrincipal.usuario_id,'key'));




    WITH Basedados DO
      BEGIN
           ProgressBar1.Value:=0;
           ProgressBar1.Max:=100;


                 { transfere os arquivois para o servidir }

               begin
                    MyAnexos := TAnexosDs.Create;
                    queryQ.Close;
                    queryQ.CommandText :=   'Select * from anexos where REPLICACAO_EFETUADA=''NÃO'' ';
                    queryQ.Open;


       ProgressBar1.Value:=0;
       ProgressBar1.Max:=QueryQ.RecordCount;
      queryQ.First;
      while NOT queryQ.Eof do
        begin
           label1.text:='Transmitindo dados do anexo  [' + IntToStr(queryQ.RecNo) + ']';
              try
                MyAnexos.LoadData(MyAnexos,QueryQ);
                Protoco := JSONToProtocolo(proxy.Receive_Anexo(MyAnexos.AnexosDs_To_JSON(MyAnexos)));
                SetProtocolo('ANEXOS', MyAnexos.id, Protoco.id);

                // Aqui chama a funcão de UpLoad    || 
                //*****************************************//
                // HERE CALL FUNCTION TO UPLOAD THE FILE IMAGE , 
                //*****************************************//
                oArquivoJSON := fArquivoParaJSON(TPath.Combine(ImgDownload,queryQ.FieldByName('url').AsString));
                Application.ProcessMessages;
                label1.Text:='Inicio do processo';
                proxy.pUploadArquivo(oArquivoJSON,queryQ.FieldByName('url').AsString);


                 ProgressBar1.VALUE:=QueryQ.RecNo;



              except
                on e: Exception do
                    begin
                    end;
              end;

                MyAnexos.LoadData(MyAnexos, queryQ);
               Protoco := JSONToProtocolo(proxy.Receive_Anexo(MyAnexos.AnexosDs_To_JSON(MyAnexos)));


          { faz o update do protocolo no objeto }
          try
          SetProtocolo('ANEXOS', MyAnexos.id, Protoco.id);
          except
            on e:exception do
                  begin
                  end;
          end;

          label1.text:='Anexo registrados, preparando para transfereir';
          queryQ.Next;
      end;

  end;
  Datasnap.Close;
  proxy.Free;
                mensagem('Envio realizado com sucesso',0);
                ModalResult:=mrOk;
                close;
         //
      end;

end;


Upload Image


function TFormSincronizacao.fArquivoParaJSON(pDirArquivo: string): TJSONArray;
var
  arq:TJSONArray;
  AFileStream: TFileStream;
begin

               AFileStream := TFileStream.Create(pDirArquivo, fmOpenRead);
               label1.Text:='Convertendo imagem ';
               arq := TDBXJSONTools.StreamToJSON(AFileStream, 0, AFileStream.Size);

               Result:=arq;

end;
```

Comment: No, because during the time of sending the image, you're locking the main thread. This is something that can be solved by performing upload in a worker thread, which reports back upload progress, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Do You give me an example of how would my code?

Comment: It's not quite so straight-forward. You'll have to study how threads work in Delphi (not very trivial) and implement it based on how your application works.

Comment: I tried to put the button
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread (
  procedure ()
  // code
  end) .Start ;

but the app processes and closes.

Comment: It's not going to be that easy, it will take quite a re-write of what you already have. Like I said, you'll have to spend some time studying threads (specifically how to `synchronize` events).